# Поиск фрагмента текста в группе файлов javascript под Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana

Пользуюсь версией *Aptana Studio 3.6.0.*

Возможно ли задать поиск фрагмента текста не в одном файле `javascript` 
*(Edit -> Find/Replace)*, а сразу в группе таких файлов, или во
всех файлах `.js` по выбранному проекту. Спасибо.

**UPD:**
Делал так, становился (выделял) нужный мне проект. Затем, после Ctrl+H, выбрал группу 
файлов .js (т.е. искать по всем файлам javascript в проекте) и выбрал фрагмент, который заведомо есть - *allfd(*. Поиск не нашел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где нужно подправить ? Thanks.

**UPD :**
Например, здесь видно, что такой фрагмент в файле есть и он встречается 5 раз.
И как-бы можно выбирать варианты Scope. Но по ним у меня не ищет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали выделить папку в проекте и потом поискать? и еще большие и маленькие буквы правильно введени?

Comment: Да, пробовал. Т.е. конечную папку, в которой лежат файлы с нужным фрагментом, выделял, - и задавал поиск. Брал простой фрагмент, - без спец_символов (думал их надо экранировать), -- тоже не находит.

Answer (score 1):

Когда ишете или заменяете с <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, оно дает возможность выбрать *workspace*, выбранные файлы или по проекту.

к примеру:

Выбераем откуда нужно искать,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом выбераем что нужно искать из каких файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

результат будет примерно таким

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь если хотите изменит слово `password` на `newpassword` на всех найденный файлах, делаем так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и начнется изменения вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и если неськолько файлов, будет вид такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для примера использовал [источник](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html?page=1)

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш развернутый ответ. А где в моем варианте 'косяк' ? empty scope, как поправить ?